# When does Apple charge its $99 Developer Program fee?

Tags: ios

Do they charge annually starting from the day I first pay, or do I need to pay once every January of every year - meaning if I register in December I need to pay $200 in the space of two months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be required to pay annual fee according to apple's custom date for you in developer website which means it counts on basis of duration (1 year). The later one doesn't make sense and pretty much discouraging user to register at later period of year. Hope this helps
P/s: Also, you can also let it expire and renew whenever you want. Your apps and balance will remain in apple server. Refer the link for further details

https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/